# I have heard that using an Elastic IP is generally considered a poor architectural design. Why so ? Why isn't an Elastic IP a suggested approach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip

I have heard that using an Elastic IP is generally considered a poor architectural design. Why so ? Why isn't an Elastic IP a suggested approach ?

Comment: Perhaps you can give more context as this seems a rather sweeping statement

Answer (score 6):

In general, applications should **avoid referring to IP addresses**. This limits their ability to point to different resources when things are changed.

Instead, it is better to use a **DNS Name**, which can be changed to point to a different IP address if anything changes.

Applications that run on a single Amazon EC2 instance might later grow to use multiple EC2 instances, fronted with a **Load Balancer**. In this situation, the DNS Name can be changed to point to a load balancer rather than a single IP address.

While **Elastic IP addresses** can be moved between instances, they are still associated with only a **single region**, and only for use within AWS, so they are not totally flexible.

The only time that an IP address is normally *required* is for **whitelisting with external services** that want to receive requests from a specific IP address.